# killing a java thread in test

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I'm writing a sort of tutorial about programming (it will be a Java repo on github) where users can clone the repo and write their own code inside empty methods to solve algorithmic problems. After they write their code, they can launch unit tests to check if their solution is correct and if it completes execution in less than a certain time (to assure they found the most efficient solution). 
So my repo will contain a lot of classes with empty methods and all the non-empty unit tests to check the code the users will write.

What I'm doing in the JUnit tests is something like that:

```
// Problem.solveProblem() can be a long running task
Thread runner = new Thread(() -> Problem.solveProblem(input)); 

runner.start();

try {
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (runner.isAlive()) {
    fail("Your algorithm is taking too long.");
    runner.stop();
}
```

Now, if a user writes a not optimized algorithm, the test fails correctly, but the `runner` thread will continue to run (and so will do the test thread) until it terminates, which can happen after minutes, though I call `running.stop()`. So I have tests that can last minutes instead of seconds like I'd like.

I know how to gracefully kill a thread in Java, but in this case I don't want the users to take care of multithreading issues (like checking/updating shared variables): I just want them to write only the code to solve the problem.

So my question is: is there a way to abruptly kill a thread in Java? If not, is there any other approach I could follow to accomplish my goal?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: If every unit test runs in a new JVM, you can possibly set the user's thread to be a daemon thread. That's supposed to let the JVM exit immediately.

Comment: If I understood correctly, a daemon thread is a thread that is killed immediately by the JVM when no other user threads are running. I've set the thread runner as daemon, but the user thread (the JUnit test) still waits for its termination before shutting down the JVM. Maybe I didn't understand how daemon thread work?

Comment: The first thing is to *not* call the `stop` method as it is deprecated and you are warned in the documentation not to use it. The second thing is that, as I said, this is going to work only if the JUnit runs in its own JVM and exits when it finishes. If the main thread terminates, and all other threads are daemon threads, the JVM is going to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with a timeout:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1); 
Future<?> future = executor.schedule(() -> Problem.solveProblem(input));
try {
    future.get(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (Exception e){
    fail("Your algorithm is taking too long.");
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Will probably require some refinements but you get the basics.

Comment: the future.cancel() doesn't seem to work: the behaviour of the test is the same as before, it just waits till the end of the execution of the  future before ending the test.

Comment: You can force a shutdown on the executor.

Comment: `ExecutorService.shutdown()` does not cause the current task to terminate. `ExecutorService.shutdownNow()` has no guarantee of success as it uses `Thread.interrupt` to try and interrupt the thread.

Comment: That's what I meant. Not fully available here

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup()` to iterate through. `Thread.stop` is the brute-force way, but in your case it'll probably work if you call `Thread.interrupt` -edit- I read this too quickly and thought you were calling sleep in your spawned threads. Rereading, I see that you are just doing this in your main thread, so as RealSkeptic commented on this post it is uncertain and probably unlikely that `interrupt` will solve the problem

Comment: Why would `interrput` work? If the thread is not in an interruptible action, that merely sets the interrupted flag. And `stop` is deprecated.

Comment: The threads that are being created (in this example at least) are calling sleep, which interrupt will wake up - check that, it's only the main thread. So in this case interrupt wouldn't work